# el modal de bootstrap no me funciona

Tags: .net, bootstrap-4, razor

quisiera saber porque el modal de mi bootstrap 4.5.0

el modal cuando le hago click no hace nada, no errores en consola ni nada, ejecuta las clases pero no muestra nada en el navegador

muestro la cabercera del layout

```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

y aqui el codigo del boton

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ayuda

Comment: Asegúrate que estas usando el bootstrap 4.5 y no el 5, porque en el 5 todos los atributos con el prefijo `data-` han cambiado a `data-bs-` y eso que cuentas suena a ese problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No considerando esta pregunta como repetida, aunque encontré algunas similares. La razón, es que dependiendo de la versión de bootstrap, cuando >= 5, la respuesta es específica:

**A partir de bootstrap 5 se debe cambiar data-toggle y data-target a data-bs-toggle y data-bs-target para que el modal html css funcione.**

Además, seguramente necesitas agregar bootstrap.bundle.min.js o bootstrap.min.js cuando menos, y siempre después de jquery en tus scripts.

El siguiente código de ejemplo es funcional con BS 5, aplicando todos los cambios:  (si realmente usas BS 4.5, mantener los atributos data-toggle y data-target)

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Test Modal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>
    
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Diría que te confundes, es a partir de la versión 5, no la 4.5.0.  Si miras [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#modal-components) verás que en la 4.6 aun usan los atributos `data-` en lugar de `data-bs-` tal como afirmas en tu resaltado. Lo explican mínimamente [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#javascript).  Aun así, el OP asegura que usa el 4.5, así que mejor esperar a que confirme si realmente lo usa o no para estar seguros de esta respuesta.

Comment: De acuerdo @masterguru, usé BS 5, aún así parte de la respuesta es el js de boostrap faltante. Editaré esa parte